# Tabris.js getting started - fail

Tags: tabris

Tabris.js claims to be simple and offers a "getting started" demo app for noobs to try for themselves with a step by step guide.

Downloading the cli tool works seamlessly, and creating the initial demo app asks clear and sensible questions: what to call the app, etc. (I chose the defaults), what source language (I chose Typescript), what IDE (I chose VSCode).

The guide says building the app is as easy as `tabris build {android|ios|windows}` but here's the kicker...

Now I'm asked for a "Build key".

WTF? What's that then? Do I make one up? What form should it take? Where do I get one from? Do I need to pay?

Go to the docs: no mention of "build key".

Search the docs: there's mention of a SSH key if I'm accessing a repo outside of Git, or a Cordova key if I'm sideloading on Windows 10. Neither of these apply.

Tabris.js looked interesting enough that I downloaded the cli and the android app, but it's just one more disappointment if the makers can't document how to get "Hello world!" off the ground.

Can anyone tell me about the build key I need when I want to build a tabris.js app?

For anyone interested, here's their doc site...
https://tabrisjs.com/documentation/latest/

Comment: As Cookie Guru pointed out, you can download your build key on your profile page on tabrisjs.com. I've updated the [documentation on local build](https://tabrisjs.com/documentation/latest/build.html#local-build) which was outdated. I think we should also improve the message printed by the CLI.

Comment: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js-cli/issues/28) for the CLI message

Comment: I must say how impressed I am with the quick and efficient response and the rapid update to the online docs. I'm looking forward to learning more about Tabris. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `tabris build <platform>`, the following output is seen:

```
$ tabris build android
[./] npm.cmd run --if-present build:android
[./] npm.cmd run --if-present build
[./] Copying Cordova files to build/cordova ...
[./] Copying JavaScript files to build/cordova/www/app/ ...
[build/cordova/www/app] npm.cmd install --production
added 7 packages in 4.173s
[./] Replacing variables in config.xml...
Build key (https://tabrisjs.com/settings/account):
```

On that prompt for the build key, there is a URL, and if you visit [that URL](https://tabrisjs.com/settings/account), you will see a key at the top of the page just under your name.  Paste that key and it will automatically download the necessary platform files.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out (and so politely - on re-reading my post today I realise it sounds like a bit of a rant, for which I apologise to all). I guess I was diverted away from the settings page by the need to log in to Github, and misdirected by LastPass auto-filling the wrong Github account credentials.

Comment: Think of it this way: Your confusion helped future users who may have been confused by the prompt as well :)
I think the updated prompt is much better; not only does it do a better job of explaining how to obtain it, but it explains _why_ such a key needs to be obtained.

Comment: @cbuteau It gets pasted in the command line.  This question is two years old; the prompt has since been updated to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks cookie guru.
The prompt did not come up and I had to kill it.
I assumed it had to go in package.jdon or some other config and everything just said paste it...